# Why are powershell variables not queryable in debug mode after upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: powershell

After being upgraded at work to Windows 10, PowerShell variables are no longer queryable in debug mode.  For example, using ISE I can run the following script

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
```

and put a breakpoint at the `$b=2` line.  Mousing over `$a` causes the common tooltip to display, but shows no value for `$a`, just `$a=`.  Also if I query it on the command line it shows no value.  On the other hand, the following script gives the correct value for `$a`:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
Write-Output $a;
```

This proves that PowerShell is functioning internally, but not allowing variables to be read in debug mode.  My own computers and VMs running Windows 10 do not have this issue.  Does anyone know of a configuration setting, or a security setting, or something else which would cause this issue?  Those responsible for the upgrade are bewildered.

Comment: Everyone's profile has the issue.  I don't have the ability to refresh my own profile, but I could probably talk them into it if I could explain why that might work?

Comment: I can't repro the issue, could you have set the breakpoint on line 2, but not yet hit it?

Comment: Thanks Burt Harris.  No, I tried to keep the example as simple as possible but it doesn't matter how many lines past or what variable I try to query.  No reports.  In this case I'm trying to get a read on $a, not $b.